# Docker buildx is required

Tags: azure, docker, github-actions

I want to deploy my application to Azure. In the past I was deploying to Azure but then GitHub domain was changed and with new one I can't deploy it.

When it comes to below lines:

```
 - name: Build and push staging images
        uses: docker/build-push-action@v2
        with:
          context: .
          tags: ${{secrets.ACR_URL_DEV}}/ocrapisdev:latest
          push: true
```

it started to give error below:

> Error: Docker buildx is required. See
> https://github.com/docker/setup-buildx-action to set up buildx.

In old GitHub domain there was  no issue like that. It started with this new domain. How can I solve this problem?

Comment: You need to set up `buildx` using that suggested action in the error before build and push. That should fix your issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As the error message says, you should add some missing step in your job, as example:

```
 - name: Set up QEMU
   uses: docker/setup-qemu-action@v1
 - name: Set up Docker Buildx
   id: buildx
   uses: docker/setup-buildx-action@v1


 - name: Build and push staging images
   uses: docker/build-push-action@v2
     with:
       context: .
       tags: ${{secrets.ACR_URL_DEV}}/ocrapisdev:latest
       push: true
```